# Slideout/Hide Toolbar on click

Tags: android

Hiding toolbar code:

```
    View toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.animate()
            .translationY(-toolbar.getHeight())
            .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
```

Toolbar xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<View 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
 />
```

I want to slide out to top a toolbar (hide it) and resize View to top. 
I want to do it not with scroll but with any event (click).
Problem with above code is toolbar hides but remains empty place of AppBarLayout. 
How to do it?

Comment: Don't hide the toolbar, hide the appbarlayout

Comment: Then remains blank rectangle

Comment: how about set visibility of AppBarLayout to `GONE` when animation end.

Comment: `GONE` works (moves view to top) but looks not good.

Answer (score 0):

I found a reason.
It was because of: `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

Deleting it fixed blank space problem but then you have to fix top margin for that bottom View.